# Changing content of a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the content "Hi" to something else when the width of screen is 480px. I tried using Pseudo elements but is not showing. Javascript, Jquery and css is fine for answer provide. Thanks!

HTML

```
<li><a href="#service-tab-1" class="service-tab-1">Hi</a></li>
```

CSS

```
#service-tabs ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #eaeaea;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following jQuery Code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).resize(function () {
    width=$(window).width();
    if (width == 480){
      $(".service-tab-1").text("something else");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="#service-tab-1" class="service-tab-1">Hi</a></li>
```

Here [`$(window).width();`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) gets the current width of the window and `$(".service-tab-1").text("something else");` changes the text of the element based on class name. And the [`$(window).resize()`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) event is sent to the window element when the size of the browser window changes

Answer (score 4):

Try like this,

```css
.service-tab-1:before {
    content: 'Hi';
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .service-tab-1:before {
        content: 'Hello';
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="#service-tab-1" class="service-tab-1"></a>
```

Comment: you're answer is great but unfortunately is not working on my side.

Comment: oh, sorry to here about it

Answer (score 0):

I have done a quick demo with the Pseudo elements [Pure CSS method]. Check out the snippet and resize it to see the text change. You can try different methods to achieve this.

Here is the [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7gmcLwfp/) if you want to play around

```css
li a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #eaeaea;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

li a:before {
  content: 'Hola';
  color: red;
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  li a{
    color: transparent;
  }
  li a:before {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<li><a href="#service-tab-1" class="service-tab-1">Hi</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use document or window as per your need with following code.

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(function(){if ($(window).width() = 480) {
      $(".service-tab-1").text("blab blab blab");
   }
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery can help with this. Just make sure to change the selectors once you incorporate it to your project.

In my snippet it changes when the screen is below or equal 480. If you want it for only 480 width, change the if to:

```
if ($(window).width() == 480)
```

Happy to help with that if needed

---

```js
if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
  $('li a').text('Something else');
}
```

```css
#service-tabs ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #eaeaea;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="#service-tab-1" class="service-tab-1">Hi</a></li>
```